# kubectl context vs cluster

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, amazon-eks

In the world of kubectl and kubernetes config, what's the difference between context and a cluster? For example I see these commands:

```
Available Commands:
  current-context Displays the current-context
  delete-cluster  Delete the specified cluster from the kubeconfig
  delete-context  Delete the specified context from the kubeconfig
  get-clusters    Display clusters defined in the kubeconfig
  get-contexts    Describe one or many contexts
  rename-context  Renames a context from the kubeconfig file.
  set             Sets an individual value in a kubeconfig file
  set-cluster     Sets a cluster entry in kubeconfig
  set-context     Sets a context entry in kubeconfig
```

and in .kube/config I see:

```
- context:
    cluster: arn:aws:eks:us-west-2:91XXXXXXX71:cluster/ignitecluster
    namespace: ignite
    user: arn:aws:eks:us-west-2:91XXXXXXX71:cluster/ignitecluster
  name: arn:aws:eks:us-west-2: 91XXXXXXX71:cluster/ignitecluster
```

Answer (score 37):

#### Clusters

Cluster is a place where all Kubernetes components, capabilities, and workloads are configured.

Clusters in Kubernetes are identified by their respective Certificate Authority (CA) certificates. For ex, let's say you have three clusters.

[image: Clusters data table]

```
rewanth@ubuntu:~$ cat ~/.kube/config
...
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority: /home/rewanth/.minikube/development-ca.crt
    server: https://192.168.177.136:8443
  name: development
...
```

#### Users

Users in Kubernetes are identified by their respective client/user certificates. For ex, let's assume you have three users.

[image: Users data table]

```
rewanth@ubuntu:~$ cat ~/.kube/config
...
users:
- name: admin
  user:
    client-certificate: /home/rewanth/.minikube/admin.crt
    client-key: /home/rewanth/.minikube/admin.key
...
```

#### Contexts

So, a user has to provide both the `cluster` certificates and `user` certificates to validate and run workloads on the targeted resource.

We need to provide three certificates to run workloads on any cluster.

- One CA certificate for cluster
- Two certificates for user: A private key and public key

**Context** makes this work easier by combining **User** and **Cluster** configurations/certificates.

[image: Context data table]

```
rewanth@ubuntu:~$ cat ~/.kube/config
...
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: staging
    user: user1
  name: Context1
- context:
    cluster: development
    user: admin
  name: Context2
- context:
    cluster: development
    namespace: private
    user: user1
  name: Context4
...
```

So, simply referring to `Context2` means we want to log in to `Development` cluster as `admin` user.

`Context4` means we want to log in to `private` namespace in `development` cluster as `user1` user.

`Context1` means we want to log in to `staging` cluster as `user1` user.

#### IMPORTANT NOTE

**Context** doesn't create new users/clusters. A context simply sets a new mapping that makes switching easier between multiple clusters.

Comment: If we omit the `namespace` does this access then applies to all `namespaces` of the `cluster` or only the `default` namespace?

Comment: The `namespace` refers to which `namespace` should be used when this context is set. If nothing is specified, the context will point to `default` namespace. For example, If you specify `kube-system`, whenever this context is used, it will be pointed to `kube-system` but you are free to switch to other namespaces. This is just a mapping. Hope this answers your question. @goulashsoup

Answer (score 33):

Cluster defines connection endpoint for Kubernetes API of a cluster.

User defines credentials for connecting to cluster.

Context defines both cluster and user.

Comment: Ok so clusters are unique, contexts are combination of cluster and user

Comment: There could be multiple contexts. However, the default currently being referred can be checked using "kubectl config view" command under current-context: {context-in-use}. And, every context is a composition of a cluster+user+namespace. If namespace is not mentioned into a cluster then it represents a default namespace.

Answer (score 13):

**Cluster**: Kubernetes brings together individual physical or virtual machines into a cluster using a shared network to communicate between each server. This cluster is the physical platform where all Kubernetes components, capabilities, and workloads are configured.

**Context**: A context is just a set of access parameters that contains a Kubernetes cluster, a user, and a namespace.

The current context is the cluster that is currently the default for kubectl and all kubectl commands run against that cluster.

Answer (score 3):

From https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/cluster-access-for-kubectl#kubeconfig:

```
A context is a group of access parameters.
Each context contains a Kubernetes cluster, a user, and a namespace.
The current context is the cluster that is currently the default for kubectl:
all kubectl commands run against that cluster
```

So, contextX = {clusterX, userX, namespaceX}